# How to create n-dimensional binary array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, roc

I want to understand how to draw ROC curve and for now I have y_score of shape (35249, 39) and I need y_true array (example: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0]).

So if I want to use roc_curve function I need to have same shapes on y_score and y_true. So for testing purposes I wanted to ask how to generate y_true array of binary data (1 and 0) of shape (35249, 39) and where element "1" occurs only one time in the array?

Comment: Add a minimal sample `y_score` and show us the expected output?

Comment: *"I have y_score of shape (35249, 39) "* - that sounds wrong to me. Assuming that you're talking about [`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html), both `y_true` and `y_score` are expected to be one dimensional arrays of shape `(n_samples,)`.

Comment: Also a ROC curve with 1 positive observation is likely to look really bad, and guarandeed to not be statistically robust.